# Updating a single page application built with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a complex social networking website that is all one single page that never refreshes unless a user presses the refresh button on the browser.

The issue here is that when I edit files and upload them to the server they don't take effect unless the user refreshes the browser.

How would I go about and fix this problem? Should I do a time interval of browser refreshes? Or should I poll the server every 10 minutes to check if the browser should do a refresh?

Any suggestions?

Comment: pass a version number along with every request as a header. if version number doesn't match, refresh.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Server

I would communicate the version number through whatever means you're already using for data transfer. Presumably that's some kind of API, but it may be sockets or whatever else.

Whatever the case, I would recommend that with each response - a tidy way is in the header, as suggested in comments by Kevin B - you transmit the current application version.

### Client

It is then up to the client to handle changes to the version number supplied. It will know from initial load and more recent requests what the version number has been up until this point. You might want to consider different behaviour depending on what the change in version is.

For example, if it is a patch number change, you might want to present to the user the option of reloading, like Outlook.com does. A feature change might do the same with a different message advertising the fact that new functionality is available, and a major version change may just disable the site and tell the user to reload to regain access.

You'll notice that I've skated around automatic reloading. This is definitely not a technical issue so much as a UX one. Having a SPA reload with no warning (which may well result in data loss) is not the best and I'd advise against it, especially for patch version changes.

**Edit**

Of course, if you're not using any kind of API or other means of dynamically communicating data with the server, you will have to resort to polling an endpoint that will give you a version and then handle it on the client in the same way. Polling isn't super tidy, but it's certainly better - in my strong opinion - than reloading on a timer on the offchance that the application has updated in the interim.

Comment: Thanks, I will create an http interceptor and send it in the header.

Comment: And by the way, whats up with the downvotes? Is this not a legit question? :/

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, and I can only guess as to why others did. There's likely a fair bit of material around the place covering your options here, but it's quite a hard issue to pick good limiting keywords for. The tagging and title probably aren't ideal, but those are also very nitpicky issues. My guess is that one person felt for whatever reason that they should downvote it, and because votes in either direction are pretty infectious in this community, someone else did too. You have my sympathies, and a compensatory upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about changing the client side code of the app or the content?  You can have the client call the server for updated content using AJAX requests, one possibility would be whenever the user changes states in the app or opens a page that loads a particular controller.  If you are talking about changing the html or javascript, I believe the user would need to reload to get those updates.